# Sort a list in flutter where 0 goes to the bottom

Tags: flutter

I am trying to sort a list from firebase and I would like for items that have a 0 value to go to the bottom.

So it currently looks like this:

[Debts not sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFNfl.png)

I would like for the top item which has a 0 value to go to the bottom and **retain the current sorting order**.

The code for the query currently looks like this:

```
          .collection('debts')
          .document(uid)
          .collection('debts')
          .orderBy('balance')         
          .snapshots()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the flag descending to true, in the orderBy clause. Like this:

```
  .collection('debts')
  .document(uid)
  .collection('debts')
  .orderBy('balance', descending: true)
  .snapshots()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is that if I sort it in descending order it messes up the order of the other debts. I would like to retain the current order and just move any 0 values to the bottom.

Comment: What do you mean by messes the order of the other debts?

Comment: The debts with a 0 value have been paid off and I would like to move them to the bottom. The other debts need to stay in order of smallest balance to largest balance. So the list needs to have the Visa card with the balance of 1180 first and the Mort which has the highest balance of 114568 last with the paid off debts below it.

Comment: I see. Did you tried using `.orderBy('debt', descending: true)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. There is no 'debt' or 'debts' field in firebase to sort by.

Comment: Oh sorry!  Otherwise I'd suggest to chain two orderBy, like this example from Firebase docs: `citiesRef.orderBy("state").orderBy("population", "desc")` , then you could try`.orderBy("balance").orderBy("debt", descending: true)`

Comment: Hey, thanks that (mostly) did it! I had to add a value in the database called 'isPaidOff' and then I ordered by(isPaidOff) then ordered by ('balance'). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.sort()` method from `List`.

Example:

```
final list = [0, 10, 5, 7, 0, 8, 2];
print(list); // [0, 10, 5, 7, 0, 8, 2]
list..sort((a, b) => a == 0 ? 1 : -1);
print(list); //[10, 5, 7, 8, 2, 0, 0]
```